# Attach a callback to run after a scala spray server successfully sends a response

Tags: scala, spray

I want to do something like the following:

```
object SprayTest extends App with SimpleRoutingApp {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
  import system.dispatcher

  startServer(interface = "0.0.0.0", port = 8080) {
    post {
      path("configNetwork") {
        entity(as[Config]) { config =>
          complete {
            // has a response indicating "OK"
            // also, restarts the network interface
            handleConfig(config)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that `handleConfig` reinitializes the network interface, so remote hosts accessing this endpoint never receive their response.

One way to solve this is to run `handleConfig` in a separate thread and complete the request immediately with some response like "OK". This isn't a good solution however because it introduces a race condition between the future and the request completion (also, it always fails if the future is executed in a "same thread" execution context).

Therefore, an ideal solution would be to attach a callback to a "write response" future and perform the network re-initialization there, after the response has been successfully sent. Is there a way to achieve this in the spray framework?

As a simple example of the race condition, consider the following two examples:

```
object SprayTest extends App with SimpleRoutingApp {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
  import system.dispatcher

  startServer(interface = "0.0.0.0", port = 8080) {
    post {
      path("configNetwork") {
        entity(as[Config]) { config =>
          ctx =>
            ctx.complete("OK")
            System.exit(0) // empty response due to this executing before response is sent
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
object SprayTest extends App with SimpleRoutingApp {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
  import system.dispatcher

  startServer(interface = "0.0.0.0", port = 8080) {
    post {
      path("configNetwork") {
        entity(as[Config]) { config =>
          ctx =>
            ctx.complete("OK")
            Thread.sleep(1000)
            System.exit(0) // response is "OK" because of the sleep
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `withAck` method on `HttpResponse` to receive notification when the response is sent on the wire. Here is a sketch of what that would look like in code, though I suspect if you're reconfiguring the low-level network interface then you will need to actually close the http listener and rebind.

```
case object NetworkReady

class ApiManager extends HttpServiceActor with Directives {

  override def receive: Receive = networkReady

  private def networkReady: Receive = runRoute(routes) orElse networkManagementEvents

  private def networkManagementEvents: Receive = {
    case Config =>
      context.become(reconfiguringNetwork)
      magicallyReconfigureNetwork pipeTo self
  }

  private def magicallyReconfigureNetwork: Future[NetworkReady] = ???

  private def reconfiguringNetwork: Receive = {
     case NetworkReady => context.become(networkReady)
     case _: HttpRequest => sender() ! HttpResponse(ServiceUnavailable)
     case _: Tcp.Connected => sender() ! Tcp.Close
  }

  private def routes: Route = {
    (post & path("configNetwork") & entity(as[Config])) { config =>
      complete(HttpResponse(OK).withAck(config))
    }
  }

}
```